# Uncertainty in Acceleration given the uncertainty in position

Tags: physics

I had a motion detector record the position of a dynamics cart and automatically plot Position vs Time and Velocity vs Time plots in *Logger Pro* on the computer. If the instrument uncertainty in position *x* was given by $\pm0.05$ (or more generally any value $\pm e$) what will be the propagated instrument uncertainty on the second derivative of position, $\ddot{x}$-i.e. acceleration?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Uncertainty is not simply *propagated*. With uncertainty of $\pm 0.05$ on value, uncertainty of derivatives could be anything (just look at $e \cos(m t)$ for arbitrary large $m$). To compute velocity or acceleration, you have to approximate the whole curve.

Answer (score 1):

I think there must be some more assumptions to be made before your question can be answered.  But here's my best shot:

If you calculate acceleration at $t_i$ as

$\frac{x_{i+1}-2x_i+x_{i-1}}{\Delta t^2}$

then each $x_n$ contributes $\Delta x$ to the uncertainty, which is then $4\Delta x/\Delta t^2$.  But wait, there's more.  Your recorded *times* are not going to be exact either.  So the uncertainty in $\Delta t$, call it $\delta t$, will also contribute to an uncertainty in acceleration.  But it doesn't sound like you are concerned with that right now, so I will stop here, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: But $\Delta x/\Delta t^2$ is *big*.